# Prevent the browser from downloading too much of a video

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, video-streaming, html5-video, buffering

I host some videos in a private bucket storage in Google Cloud Storage.
The duration of these videos are quite long (about an hour each) but I would like to display in loop only 3 to 4 seconds of these videos (for example between times 1120s to 1123s).
The problem is that even when I give the `<video>` tag the right URL (something like https://mybucket.storage.googleapis.com/path-to-my-video.mp4?access_token=...t=1120,1123), the browser (Chrome or Firefox) still downloads approx. 10 Mb of data, which is a bit long for the 3 seconds to play.
It seems like the browser downloads way more data than it needs to play the range that I want so I'm looking for a way to just load the minimal amount of data to play my range.

I have already tried `preload="metadata"` and added these event listeners to make sure the video never plays outside the boundaries :

```html
<video controls preload="metadata"
          src={`${videosRootUrl}/${videoMetadata.name}/${videoMetadata.name}.mp4?access_token=${accessToken}#t=${from},${to}`}
          onError={err => handleVideoError(err)}
          onTimeUpdate={e => handleTimeUpdate(e, from, to)}
          onLoadedMetadata={e => onloadedmetadata(e.currentTarget, from)}
        >
```

```js
  function handleTimeUpdate(event, from, to) {
    const videoElt = event.currentTarget
    const currentTime = videoElt.currentTime
    if(currentTime < from || currentTim
    }
  }
  function onloadedmetadata(video, from) {
    video.currentTime = from;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Storage doesn't have the ability to deal with video-specific as you would expect from a video streaming service.  You can't scrub to specific points in time or resample the quality.  All GCS can do is deliver the entire contents of the object, and it doesn't really care what the object contains.  As such, should expect that the browser will start downloading from the beginning and continue downloading as it plays the content.

See also:

- [Video Streaming from Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949662/video-streaming-from-google-cloud-storage)
- [Streaming videos from Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266198/streaming-videos-from-google-cloud)

Comment: It actually can get you a specific part of the data if you [specify a Range](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-download-byte-range) so that's all a browser needs to go to a specific location in the video.
In my examples, I could directly go to the end of the video. It's just that no matter how short my initial time boundaries were, the browser downloads ~10Mb of data.

Comment: @user9709036 So you'd have to know the specific byte range for the time range in question, which is basically impossible without a lot of prior knowledge (and if you did, you'd already have the file downloaded and processed locally, which removes the need for GCS to do the "streaming" in the first place).

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding about my problem. What I want to know is not that much about GCS but about the capabilities of HTML5 and the video tag. I need to find a way to tell the browser to just get the metadata of my file and then to download just the part I need from the content. I think Media Source API could be a good candidate but it seemoverly complicated for my need.